# JBoss 7 troubleshooting slowness

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We have an application on JBoss 7.1.0 istance, usually running ok but sometime the performance degrading, in this case a restart of JBoss is useful.
I have configured an access.log to record the timing of the pages and when the performance are degrading, we have an increase in recorded time on it for some pages.

How can I better identify and troubleshoot the problem? I think can be a problem related to objects in memory of JBoss server.

I exclude can be a memory issue on client because the access.log record the slow time, is it right or can I be misinterpreting the access.log and the problem can be also on client?

The ram / cpu on server are not under load when there are slowness and the xmx is oversized.
The JBoss is on Windows with JDK 1.7.0_80.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:** Our degrading performance problem was related to an APM configured to record too much data and solved by removing it (are needed to be better configured).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JBOSS server has a problem. By reading your statement, I think the your code is leaking connections. Login into JBOSS Console and see the stats of your connection pools (you need to enable stats if not enabled already). If the connection count grows linearly and never comes down then you need to fix the leakage at code level. You can also use JConsole to monitor JVM memory and detect problems.

Answer (score -1):

I faced an increase of tcp connections, trend shows TCP connections are  growing and growing, restart jboss application -service looks remediate the issue for some time